How to deploy nuxt web app to Azure web app?
I have a web app based on nuxt, node.js and vue. It's working fine locally by running yarn install, then yarn dev. But after yarn build, I ftp the folder to azure web app wwwroot, I got Your web app is running and waiting for your content. In another instance, I got the error below:
:( Application Error
If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.

What's the correct way to ftp the content to azure web app?
export default {
  telemetry: false,
  // Target (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target)
  target: 'server'

  // Global page headers (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head)
  head: {
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    }
  }
}

I tried ftp and I expect the site will be loading.
